# Is Stereo Mix audio device hardware or software?

Tags: windows, realtek-hd-audio

So to elaborate on this, I wanted to do a loop from headphone to mic to find device response for calibration but it disables the mic as it detects a short and my device only has a 3.5mm combo jack not dedicated mic and headphone. So now to the original question is Stereo Mix audio device hardware or software?
If its hardware then I can use it for loopback but if its software then its pointless.

Comment: As far as i'm aware, the Stereo Mix in windows is provided by the audio driver. So it would depend on the driver's implementation ?